# Determinant function bounded/continuous

Tags: linear-transformations, determinant

I'm reading through my lecture notes and noticed that I can combine theorems to show det:$ \mathbb{K}^{n \times n} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is continuous (and bounded). Looking at the det function in terms of the sum of entries and corresponding entries of the cofactor matrix it's obvious it is continuous, but I want to know if my thinking is correct so I can apply it to similar situations.

(1) A linear map from a finite dimensional vector space to a normed space is bounded.

(2) Boundedness and continuity are equivalent for a linear map between $2$ normed spaces.

If we regard matrices in $\mathbb{K}^{n \times n}$ as an t-tuple of vectors in $\mathbb{K}^n$, then the determinant function det:$ \mathbb({K}^{n})^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is an n-multilinear function of the row or columns of the matrix. Then viewing this multilinear map as a linear-map-valued linear map, we can apply (1) and (2) to show that it is bounded and continuous.

Not really a question, but like I said I'm just playing around with the theorems and definitions to see if I understand it, so if I have made a mistake please let me know!

Comment: Why do you think it is bounded? For $n=1$, $\det:\mathbb K\to \mathbb K$ is an isomorphism and $\mathbb K$ is definitely not bounded. Just think of $\mathbb R$!

Comment: @James  a bounded functional need not be bounded as a function, though.

Comment: @Randall I see. So I was just taking the wrong notion of boundedness.. Thanks!

Comment: It’s not entirely clear.

Comment: So by bounded I mean bounded on the unit ball, this isn't really useful as such for this function but the fact that it is continuous is I think

Comment: If OP meant bounded as a function then you are correct and that could be an answer. @James

Comment: @Displayname  in that case it’s simpler:   det is just a polynomial so of course it’s bounded on the unit ball.